# Edit distance such as Levenshtein taking into account proximity on keyboard

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

Is there an edit distance such as Levenshtein which takes into account distance for substitutions?

For example, if we would consider if words are equal, `typo` and `tylo` are really close (`p` and `l` are physically close on the keyboard), while `typo` and `tyqo` are far apart. I'd like to allocate a smaller distance to more likely typos.

There must be a metric that takes this kind of promixity into account?

Comment: You mean [Damerau-Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: I saw it, but hadn't realized that "transposition of adjacent characters" is actually what I meant. Though I guess I'm looking not only for adjacent characters, but more of a quadratic weighted distance (not only adjacent) Thanks!

Comment: I think adjacent in that scheme is talking about tansposing characters that are adjacent within the word (e.g. want vs wnat), rather than adjacent on a keyboard.

Comment: @JRichardSnape "Plot-twist" indeed....

Comment: Did you try combining Damerau-Levenshtein (or replacing, if you really only want to consider keyboard "misses") with some kind of Euclidian distance as suggested in the @marmeladze answer?  Seems like the way to go to me, or is there more to consider / it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 24):

the kind of distance you ask is not included in levenshtein - but you should use a helper like euclidean or manhattan distance, to get the result. my simple assumption is, **q** (in english qwerty layout) is cartesian (y=0; x=0)
so, **w** will be (y=0; x=1) and so on. [whole list here](https://replit.com/@marmeladze1/Cartesian-QWERTY?v=1)

```
keyboard_cartesian= {
                     'q': {'y': 0, 'x': 0},
                     'w': {'y': 0, 'x': 1},
                     'e': {'y': 0, 'x': 2},   
                     'r': {'y': 0, 'x': 3},    
                      # ...
                     'a': {'y': 1, 'x': 0}, 
                      #...
                     'z': {'y': 2, 'x': 0},
                     'x' : {'x':1, 'y':2},
                      #   
                     }
```

assume, word qaz has a meaning. levenshtein distance between `qaz`  and with both of `waz` and `eaz` is 1. to check out which misspell is more likely, take the differences (here (q,w) and (q,e)) and calculate euclidean distance

```
>>> from math import *
>>> def euclidean_distance(a,b):
...     X = (keyboard_cartesian[a]['x']-keyboard_cartesian[b]['x'])**2
...     Y = (keyboard_cartesian[a]['y']-keyboard_cartesian[b]['y'])**2
...     return sqrt(X+Y)
... 
>>> euclidean_distance('q', 'w')
1.0 
>>> euclidean_distance('q', 'e')
2.0
```

this means misspell of **qaz** as **waz** is more likely than **qaz** as **eaz**.

Comment: The link seems to be dead. Can you [edit] to include a working link?

Answer (score 9):

http://www.melissadata.com/webhelp/ssis/updated/Components/Fuzzy_Match/Algorithms.htm mentions: "*Needleman-Wunsch - A variation of the Levenshtein algorithm. Levenshtein and Needleman-Wunsch are identical except that character mistakes are given different weights depending on how far two characters are on a standard keyboard layout. For example: A to S is given a mistake weight of 0.4, while A to D is a 0.6 and A to P is a 1.0*" but the [Needleman-Wunsch Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) does not mention keyboard layout proximity... But maybe you should look into that.