# How to make spelling does not count in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
    if @msg =~ /facebook/i
        puts "Nice job, you got it!"
    end
```

I want to make a trivia game that would somehow do not care about spelling count if a person typed in `facebook` as the answer to the game.

if someone accidentally typed in  `faceboko, fecabook, or ftckbook`, it would work and give an output of "Nice job, you got it!"

I don't know how I would start it.

Comment: It's `/facebook/i`, not `\facebook\i`.

Comment: You can use edit distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) distance is used to handle such problems.

You can implement your own solution - but there is a good [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/levenshtein) which uses [native C bindings](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/levenshtein/0.2.2/Levenshtein#distance-class_method).

Define an error rate (e.g. 4) and check the distance between user input and original string.

```
2.2.2 :001 > require "levenshtein"
 => true 
2.2.2 :002 > Levenshtein.distance("facebook", "ftcebook")
 => 1
```

So, if you use this, your code will become,

```
err = 4
if Levenshtein.distance("original", @msg)>err
  "Nice job"
end
```

This also may be useful - [Edit distance such as Levenshtein taking into account proximity on keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233888/edit-distance-such-as-levenshtein-taking-into-account-proximity-on-keyboard/29590495#29590495)