# To add and remove random letters to/from each word in a given string

Tags: python, random

The following code generates random typos:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51080546
import string
import random

phrase = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum."
# probability for a word to change
p = 0.8

new_phrase = []
words = phrase.split(' ')
for word in words:
    outcome = random.random()
    if outcome <= p:
        ix = random.choice(range(len(word)))
        new_word = ''.join([word[w] if w != ix else random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for w in range(len(word))])
        new_phrase.append(new_word)
    else:
        new_phrase.append(word)

new_phrase = ' '.join([w for w in new_phrase])

print(new_phrase)
```

How is it possible to make it also add and remove random letters to/from each word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add random letters, change `random.choice(string.ascii_letters)` to `word[w] + random.choice(string.ascii_letters)`.

To remove random letters, change `random.choice(string.ascii_letters)` to `''`.